# Core-Plot multiple y axis alignment issues - possibly related to scaling

Tags: ios, core-plot, graphing

My Issues is as follows:

I'm trying to graph two data sets (One is in Feet and one is in degrees) in such a way that they can be compared (they do share a common x-axis value).

As you can see my data seems to be interlaced correctly but I'm having trouble getting the yAxises to behave as I'd like.  I would like the X-Axis Max/Min to actually line up with both Y-Axises.  My code is as follows:

```
- (void)initPlot {
    [self loadCoreData];
    [self configureHost];
    [self configureGraph];
    [self configurePlots];
    [self configureAxes];
}

- (void)configureHost {
    self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.hostView];
}

- (void)configureGraph {
    // 1 - Create the graph
    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
    [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];
    self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;


    // 2 - Set graph title

    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Altitude Plot [%@ to %@]",        self.flightRecording.originAirport,     self.flightRecording.destinationAirport];

    graph.title = title;


    // 3 - Create and set text style
    CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
    graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
    graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
    graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, -20.0f);


    // 4 - Set padding for plot area
    float padding = 10.0f;
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:padding];
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:50.0f];
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingRight:padding];
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingTop:padding];

    // 5 - Enable user interactions for plot space
    altSpace= (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    altSpace.allowsUserInteraction = NO;

    rollSpace = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];
    rollSpace.allowsUserInteraction = NO;
    [self.hostView.hostedGraph addPlotSpace:rollSpace];

//
//    pitchSpace = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];
//    pitchSpace.allowsUserInteraction = NO;
//    [self.hostView.hostedGraph addPlotSpace:pitchSpace];
//
//
//    slipSpace = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];
//    slipSpace.allowsUserInteraction = NO;
//    [self.hostView.hostedGraph addPlotSpace:slipSpace];
//
//
//    gSpace = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];
//    gSpace.allowsUserInteraction = NO;
//    [self.hostView.hostedGraph addPlotSpace:gSpace];
}

- (void)configurePlots {
    // 1 - Get graph and plot space
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;




    // 2 - Create the three plots

    // Custom AHRS Plot
    CPTScatterPlot *ahrsAltPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    ahrsAltPlot.dataSource = self;
    ahrsAltPlot.identifier = @"AHRSALT";
    CPTColor *ahrsAltColor = [CPTColor yellowColor];
    [graph addPlot:ahrsAltPlot toPlotSpace:altSpace];


    CPTScatterPlot *rollPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    rollPlot.dataSource = self;
    rollPlot.identifier = @"ROLL";
    CPTColor *rollColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
    [graph addPlot:rollPlot toPlotSpace:rollSpace];

    // 3 - Set up plot space
    CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [altSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
    xRange=[CPTMutablePlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(maxEpoch + 300.0f )];


//    [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];
    altSpace.xRange = xRange;

    CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [altSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
    yRange = [CPTMutablePlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(maxAlt)];
    [yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.2f)];

    altSpace.yRange = yRange;

    rollSpace.xRange = xRange;

    CPTMutablePlotRange *yRangeRoll =[CPTMutablePlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0 ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(40 )];


    [yRangeRoll expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.2f)];

    rollSpace.yRange =  yRangeRoll;

    [altSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:ahrsAltPlot, nil] ];
    [rollSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rollPlot, nil]  ];

    [rollSpace setYRange:yRangeRoll];



    // 4 - Create styles and symbols


    // AHRS Style
    CPTMutableLineStyle *ahrsLineStyle = [ahrsAltPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];

    ahrsLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
    ahrsLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
    ahrsAltPlot.dataLineStyle = ahrsLineStyle;

}

- (void)configureAxes {
    // 1 - Create styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;


    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];


    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTextStyle.fontSize = 11.0f;


    CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;


    CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;


    // 2 - Get axis set
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;


    // 3 - Configure x-axis
    CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.title = @"Flight Time";
    x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    x.titleOffset = 15.0f;
    x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;


    NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet new];
    NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet new];

    NSInteger i = 0;

    for (i; i < maxEpoch; i += 600) {

        int hour = i / (68 * 60);
        int min   = i / 60;
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", hour, min] textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];

        CGFloat location = i++;
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
        label.offset = x.majorTickLength;

        if (label) {
        [xLabels addObject:label];
        [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
        }
    }


    x.axisLabels = xLabels;
    x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;
    // 4 - Configure y-axis


    CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.title = @"Altitude in Feet";
    y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    y.titleOffset = 20.0f;
    y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;


    y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    y.labelOffset = 21.0f;


    y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorTickLength = 20.0f;
    y.minorTickLength = 10.0f;

    y.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;



    // Axis #2

    CPTXYAxis *yRoll = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
    yRoll.title = @"Degrees";

    // Styling
    yRoll.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    yRoll.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    yRoll.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    yRoll.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;

    yRoll.plotSpace = rollSpace;
    yRoll.delegate = self;
    yRoll.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;

    yRoll.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
    yRoll.tickDirection = CPTSignNone;
    yRoll.separateLayers = NO;

    yRoll.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;

    yRoll.labelOffset = 21.0f;

    yRoll.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:40.0];

    yRoll.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f);

    NSMutableSet *rollLabels = [NSMutableSet new];
    NSMutableSet *rollLocations = [NSMutableSet new];

    for (int i =0; i <= 40; i+= 5) {

        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d˚", (i - 20)] textStyle:yRoll.labelTextStyle];
        CGFloat location = i;
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
        label.offset = -16.0f;

        if (label) {
            [rollLabels addObject:label];
            [rollLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
        }
    }

    yRoll.axisLabels = rollLabels;
    yRoll.majorTickLocations = rollLocations;


    NSInteger majorIncrement = 500;
    NSInteger minorIncrement = 100;
    CGFloat yMax = maxAlt;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
    NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];


    for (NSInteger j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement) {
        NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrement;
        if (mod == 0) {
            CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i ft", j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];

            NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j);
            label.tickLocation = location;
            label.offset = -y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;
            if (label) {
                [yLabels addObject:label];
            }
            [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
        } else {
            [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];
        }
    }



    // Position the y2 axis
//    y2.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:40.0];

    axisSet.yAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:40.0];

    y.axisLabels = yLabels;
    y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
    y.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;

    self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x,y,yRoll,nil];


    // Position floating YAxis
//    y2.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:150.0];
}
```

[image]

EDIT::

I tried adding the following lines and they did nothing either

```
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f);
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f);
```

I seem to be making progress actually:  It appears that if I remove

```
yAxis2.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:40.0];
```

Then my axis actually seems to pin to the x-axis (although its off the screen) now but its a start.

Comment: Do you want the plots to extend past the axes as they do now and cut off the ends of the axes or bring everything in so the axes fall on the edges of the plot area?

Comment: I would like everything to be inside the axis boundaries.  I'm confused how to do this with multiple plot spaces.  I have two plot spaces which (i think) both use the same x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved:

I had some conflicting directives going on.

In order to achieve what I needed I had to use the two calls:

```
yAxis2.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f);
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(maxEpoch); // maximum X value
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f);
```

Then in order to make sure everything could be seen correctly I had to play with the padding values:

```
float padding = 50.0f;
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:padding];
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:50.0f];
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingRight:padding];
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingTop:padding];
```

And I had to remove all the constraints that were messing with things:

```
//    yAxis2.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:40.0];
//    y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:150.0];
```

[image]